# Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - org/json/simple/JSONValue

Tags: java, jar, codenameone, yandex-api

I wanted to use the yandex api translate
It works in Java project but not in Codename One project

I followed these steps to add an api in a project like i did in java project: https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api

i want to translate what is in the label when i click on a button
i modified the key with mykey for confidential information

```
         b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                Translate.setKey("mykey");
            try {
                setTranslatedText(Translate.execute("bonjour", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ldesc2.setText("Description (Anglais):"+getTranslatedText());



        }
    });
```

When i clicked i have an Error:Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - org/json/simple/JSONValue
[image]

Comment: Is this library bundled with your app? How do you pack your application?

Comment: i m just executing it with IDE intellij

Comment: Seems library is not added to the run classpath. Is it possible to provide sample project example for investigation?

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: You can't just add an external library to Codename One, we won't be able to translate that library to any platform and it just won't work. You need to use native interfaces or implement things using a cn1lib. In this case you can just use the REST API instead of the Java API from yandex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar thing when trying to add an external library (I was trying to use javax.mail). I had a separate program that worked perfectly but when implemented into my codename one project I got the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error. The issue is codename one does not work with external libraries, only codename one extensions. If you go into preferences and look at the extensions tab, you can search for a library that does a similar thing.

Comment: i m programming with Intellij, how can i find it ?